# convert values to multi-line bar graphs in the terminal

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

Let's say I have a string of single-character values like `3121`. I would like to print it in a more graphical way. It would be relatively trivial to convert it (using `sed`/`awk`) to horizontal bars to get something like:

```
3 ###
1 #
2 ##
1 #
```

You can convert each value, `echo` the result, and move on.

But what if I want to convert them to vertical bars like this:

```
#
# #
####
3121
```

I am struggling to figure out an efficient way to horizontally append multi-line output. I am sure some variation of this question was asked before, but I can't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If gawk is available, how about:

```
#!/bin/bash

s="3121"
awk -v s="$s" 'BEGIN {
    len = split(s, ary, "");
    # store characters in a matrix a[i,j]
    for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
        a[i,1] = ary[i];
        for (j = 1; j <= ary[i]; j++) {
            a[i,j+1] = "#";
        }
        if (p < ary[i]) p = ary[i];
    }
    # print a[i,j] in a transposed order
    for (j = p + 1; j >= 1; j--) {
        str = "";
        for (i = 1; i <= len; i++) {
            if (a[i,j] == "") a[i,j] = " ";
            str = str a[i,j]; 
        }
        print str;
    }
}'
```

which yields:

```
#   
# # 
####
3121
```

Comment: Are you sure gawk is required? I tried this on Mac and it works. I thought Mac does not use gawk.

Comment: Good to know it works on Mac as well. I mentioned gawk just because of the split() function. I might have been too conservative about its availability.